# Django-dsl-drf Exclude phrase query

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am working on integrating **Elastic Search** in my **existing Django REST** application. I am using the django-dsl-drf module provided in the link below:

https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/

In their documentation **'exclude'** query param is provided. But the query only when we provide the full field value.

search-url?exclude=<field-value

For eg: If I have a value 'Stackoverflow' in field 'name'. I'll have to provide query param a
**?name__exclude=Stackoverflow** to exclude records having 'Stackoverflow' as name in the result. I would like to implement a search in such a way that when I  provide 'over', **I need** to exclude these records, similar to ?name__exclude=over

I checked the above tutorial, but I couldn't find it. Is there any work around so that I can exclude records, fields containing terms instead of providing full field value, which is also case-insensitive.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`contains` functional filter](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filtering_usage_examples.html#contains), you can target documents that have their name field value containing the characters `over` anywhere in their terms:

```
?name__contains=over
```

However, as far as I know, there is no way to **negate** that filter in django-dsl-drf. You can [create an issue](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/issues) requesting that feature, though, because odds are high that you're not the only who needs that, since it's a pretty common way of searching.

Comment: I created a new issue in their repo. In the meantime, I tweaked exclude functionality to suit my requirement.

Comment: Great, glad you figured your way into this!